# Installed standalone Python 3.7 after Anaconda Python 3.7, how to access old/specific pip?

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda

I'm relatively new to Python. I installed 3.7 as part of Anaconda package, but it wasn't working with PowerBI since it wasn't able to execute a certain batch file that started the conda venv. A workaround I read about was to install a regular Python 3.7 outside of conda and use that interpreter instead.

It successfully installed, and it was added to path, and when I do pip-list in my command prompt I see only the packages for the new pip which makes sense. How do I access the old pip for my conda python where it had all the packages?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how do you install packages in your default Python environment outside of Conda? To achieve this you'd just run pip install to install the packages fresh. If you want the list of previously install items you can use pip list.

```
conda activate myoldenv
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

You can then open requirements.txt to see which packages that you want.

However if you want PBI to work well with Python the cleanest way in my opinion is to setup within a new conda env. The point of Conda is to have different envs for different use cases.

```
conda create --name VisualisationPBI python=3.7
conda activate VisualisationPBI
pip install seaborn #installs seaborn and dependencies including numpy, pandas and mpl
```

In PBI options set your Python home directory to "Other" then select your conda directory, probably:
C:\Users\YOURNAME.conda\envs\VisualisationPBI

Conda works with PBI, but you need to Pip install the key packages in the library, instead of conda install. As here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Python-with-Anaconda-missing-dependency/td-p/665102